# The Merge is not yet available for this network! PUSH0 error

Tags: go-ethereum, nethereum, the-merge

We've recently started having trouble deploying contracts for initial testing on a Geth node running in --dev mode. The error is invalid opcode: PUSH0.

We start Geth with
'geth --http --dev --dev.period 13 --datadir [some path] --keystore [some path] --ipcdisable'

The startup messages include the message 'The Merge is not yet available for this network!', so we're wondering if this has something to do with it as PUSH0 was introduced post merge.

We're compiling our contracts with latest solc (0.8.20) and deploying and interacting using dotnet via Netheruem.

Is there a problem with --dev mode in Geth?